# When reinstalling apps/ game reset and started all over

Tags: google-play-store, htc-desire

I got a new phone and when I go to the play store it shows all the game apps and updates I installed over the past 2 years, but when I try to reinstall the game it resets and starts all over, is there a way I can get back to the level I was on instead of starting all over again ?? Please help I worked hard to reach this status in the game and I don"t want to start all over again. I f I try to add my old google account it gives me problems because it sync'd my Google and Yahoo accounts together and I don"t know the old password from 3 years ago.

Thank You,
Christina

Comment: What game are you talking about?  Can help in identifying what can be done to restore your access.

Comment: I was playing  Restaurant  Story & Dragon  Story. Tried to save game from my phone to my SD Card, but it still started all over again. Never tried rooting, not very tech. save 

Answer (score 0):

Do you root your phones?  There is an app called "Titanium Backup" that can back up and restore an app's local data, which should include the game data.  It needs root though.

If you are not comfortable with rooting or don't know what it is, that might not be an easy option for you though.

Lifehacker suggests Helium App Sync and Backup, which doesn't require root.  I haven't tried it, but LH usually offers good suggestions:

http://lifehacker.com/5843206/how-to-upgrade-to-a-new-android-phone-and-take-everything-with-you